# VBA Code for counting Values in a column

Tags: vba, count

Can anyone please tell me how to write VBA code for the following instance?
I have data for 12 weeks for 8 students for their attendance on every week. 
I already wrote a code for filling the color of the cell with red in case of Absent and with green in case of Present.

Now I have to add number of "Absent" for every student in each row and fill that number in next column. Similarly count number of absents for individual student in each row and fill that number in another column.
then finally, I should calculate the "present" percentage for each student.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPaste()
'
' CopyPaste Macro
'

    Sheets("Attendance").Select
    Range("A1:M9").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Report").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Sub Filling()
'
' Filling Macro
'

    Dim Cell As Range
    Sheets("Report").Select
    For Each Cell In Range("B2:M9")
    If Cell.Value = "Present" Then
        Cell.Interior.Color = 255
    ElseIf Cell.Value = "Absent" Then
        Cell.Interior.Color = 5287936
    Else
        'do nothing
    End If
    Next Cell
End Sub

Sub Calculate()
'
' Calculate Macro
'
    Sheets("report").Select
    Range("N1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total Present"
    Range("N2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "7"
    Range("N3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "8"
    Range("N4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "4"
    Range("N5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "7"
    Range("N6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "8"
    Range("N7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "7"
    Range("N8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "4"
    Range("N9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "7"
    Range("O1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total Absent"
    Range("O2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "5"
    Range("O3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "4"
    Range("O4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "8"
    Range("O5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "5"
    Range("O6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "4"
    Range("O7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "5"
    Range("O8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "8"
    Range("O9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "5"
    Range("P1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Attendance Rate"
    Range("P2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-2]*100)/12"
    Range("P2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("P2:P9"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("P2:P9").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need VBA for any of that. You can use Conditional Formatting for the colors, and `SumIf` for the totals.

Comment: Dear Doug
I am studying VBA for first time and this is an Assignment. I can do it with out code. I am struck with counting the number of absents and presents in a row. I would be grateful if you can help me.

Comment: Can you show the layout - how is "absent" marked? You can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf`. If you show the code you already have it should be easy to show you how to add the extra lines.

Comment: I see. In that case, please show us the code you've already got. If you can do it in Excel itself, I'd try turning on the Macro Recorder, adding the formulas, and trying to modify that.

Comment: sorry just give me a minute I am trying to upload my excel file and do not know where to and how to do it

Comment: I already did that..! I got the first two tasks done by copying and pasting the data in a different sheet and then doing the coloring..! now stuck with Counting and calculating percentage ..!

Comment: @user3268372 - edit your question to paste the code you tried to paste as a comment (where it is unreadable...)

Comment: Thank you I posted my code..!

Comment: Can any one has any idea with this problem ?

Comment: @DougGlancy Can you please show me a way of showing you my excel sheet..?

Comment: This needs to be closed as "too broad" - it's a do-it-for-me-plz question.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for inspiration:

```
Sub countAbsence()
Dim r As Range
Dim c
Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A8")
c = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r, "yes")
MsgBox "column A has " & c & " instances of 'yes'"
End Sub
```

Ask if you need more explanation.

If you want to put the count somewhere, and the percentage, you could do:

```
Range("B1").value = c
Range("C1").value = c / 8
Range("C1").style = "percent"
```

**update** complete code to take the table in `A2:M9` and generate columns of 'present', 'absent' , and 'attendance rate':

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub calculcatePresentAbsent()
  Dim absent, present
  Dim i
  Dim record As Range, target As Range

  Set record = Range("B1:M1")
  Set target = Range("N1")
  target.Value = "present"
  target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "absent"
  target.Offset(0, 2).Value = "attendance rate"

  For i = 1 To 8 ' loop over students
    Set record = record.Offset(1, 0)  ' go to next row
    Set target = target.Offset(1, 0)
    absent = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(record, "Absent")
    present = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(record, "Present")
    target.Value = present
    target.Offset(0, 1).Value = absent
    target.Offset(0, 2).Value = present / (present + absent)
    target.Offset(0, 2).Style = "percent"
  Next

End Sub
```

This basically does everything your posted code does - except it does it "dynamically", instead of with hard coded numbers.

Good luck with your class.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this..! and will let you know

Comment: OK. Happy to explain more if you implement this and get stuck!

Comment: Hey @Floris,
I tried with that code but din get it right. May be my explaining the problem was wrong. Is there anyway that I can send you the excel file or atleast an image of the question so that you would have a clear idea? Thank you again